# How time series data can be spread evenly across the cluster?

Tags: hbase

I designed the row key of a HBase table as follows:

```
<clustering-prefix><yyyyMMdd><type><uid>
```

where the *clustering-prefix* is a two digit string allowing me to spread the load of a single day into the entire cluster, by grouping events into clusters.

I also created the table using the *SPLITS_FILE* clause, with the following split sequence:

```
002015010
012015010
022015010
032015010
042015010
...
992015010
012015011
022015011
...
```

This allows to send load to 100 regions in parallel, with pretty good performance, considering that the data is time-series.

Unfortunately, I noticed that many regions that are going to be filled in parallel (the *day* part is the same) are hosted by the same region server. That is, for example:

```
002015010 -> region_server_01 *
012015010 -> region_server_02
022015010 -> region_server_01 *
032015010 -> region_server_06 **
042015010 -> region_server_03
052015010 -> region_server_01 *
062015010 -> region_server_06 **
```

Ideally, if I have 100 region servers, I would like to assign regions in such a way that regions with a different clustering prefix (first two digits) are hosted by different region servers as much as possible.

I tried changing the order of region splits in *SPLITS_FILE* but the behavior didn't change.

The reason for this kind of row is related to read and write requirements:

- **Write**: events of a single day with different clustering prefixes will be written concurrently as they arrive
- **Read**: after some amount of time, events with the same clustering prefix received in a date range should be processed in batch by a Spark job

**Question**

Is there a way to configure HBase (AssignmentManager ?) for assigning different clustering prefixes to different region servers ?

Seems that the behaviour of the assignment process is random by default.

Answer (score 0):

Only use the salt when setting the splits:

```
create 't1', 'f1', {SPLITS => ['01', '02', '03', '04' ... '99']}
```

Rowkeys starting with 00.... will be assigned to region 1

Rowkeys starting with 01.... will be assigned to region 2

Rowkeys starting with 02.... will be assigned to region 3

And so on... HBase load balancer will take care of regions distribution across your regionservers depending on the load (number of regions assigned to each server)

---

BTW, your examples have 9 chars, according to what you said, they should be 10 (2 for salt + 8 for date).

Comment: Yes, I am trying to follow the rule oh thumb of 100-200 regions per server and I included some chars of the date in the splits. I didn't include the full date as it would produce more regions than needed, so I used only the first 7 chars (about 10 days in the same region for each salting-prefix).

Comment: Using only the salting prefix as split is somewhat limiting in my case because, when the data is going to be read in batch, it would be read from only one region of the cluster. I need to spread it also by (part of the) date.

Comment: Salting prefix for each inserted row should be a randomized number to assure even distribution among the regions (which will be distributed across servers), if you need more regions just create a bigger prefix (i.e: 000 to 999, or even 0000 to 9999). Please describe how are you generating your salting prefix when writing data and what your read pattern will be.

Comment: You are right about the salting prefix, so I changed the name to *clustering prefix* as it is more appropriate in this case (the values are not random). I added also information about read and write path.

Comment: It's clearer now, so, you want to ensure maximum distribution without loosing the hability to do partial scans... sadly, that's not possible. You're going to need to perform full table scans when data is distributed across regions, but you can use column families and timeranges in your favour to reduce the amount of data is scanned, with the proper amount of regionservers and a good distribution it shouldn't be a problem. There is really no ideal solution for your problem, it depends mostly on your patterns, common date ranges scanned, amount of different event types... good luck!